# How to get second " " with indexOf in a scanner

Tags: javascript, indexof

Just started learning JavaScript, and for an assignment I have to take someones address and take out each part, but I don't know how to get the second " " with indexOf

ex)   123 fake street

```
String s = indexOf(" ");
```

How do I get the second space though?

can only use indexOf and substring

Comment: I was making an example for this and i realized... you don't even have to use indexOf(); -- You can use String.split();

Comment: @Feathercrown, yeah exactly - much easier if he does. See my answer.

Comment: cna only use indexOf and substring

Comment: "And substring" String.substring() pretty much is String.split()

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Java? This is Javascript

Comment: @Feathercrown It was tagged under Java. Check the history

Comment: Ah. Well, at least it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)

Once you know where the first one is, search after it with start

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like:

```
var address = "123 fake street";
var split_address = address.split(" "); // ["123", "fake", "street"]
```

You then have access to each part of the address like this:

```
split_address[0] === "123"
split_address[1] === "fake"
split_address[2] === "street"
```

Comment: can only use indexOf of and substring, nothing outside that, sorry :/

Comment: This is overkill and memory expensive for the sake of finding the position of a substring

Comment: If he was trying to "get out each part" this is a good way.